# projection property in subquery nhibernate criteria

Tags: sql, nhibernate, criteria, projection, restrictions

Here's the deal, I got 2 tables:

```
table (A) with columns ( colA_1  | colA_2 | colA_ID ) <br>
table (B) with columns ( colB )
```

and I'm using `DetachedCriteria.For<AnyEntity>()` to query SQL.

The purpose is get an sql senerated like this:

```
Select A.colA_ID from A 
where (CAST(colA_1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(colA_2 AS VARCHAR(10))) 
in (select colB from B)
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would strongly recommend to create a special property on your A entity:

```
public class EntityA
{
    ...
    public virtual string ProjectedKey { get; set; } 
}
```

And map it as readonly with formula

```
<property name="ProjectedKey" 
          formula="(CAST(colA_1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(colA_2 AS VARCHAR(10)))" 
          insert="false" update="false" />
```

And now is easy to use subquery

```
// subquery to get colB (its id?) from table B
var detachedQuery = DetachedCriteria.For<EntityB>()    
     .SetProjection(Projections.Id()) // or property representing col B

// use subquery with property represented by formula
var rootQuery = session.CreateCriteria<EntityA>()
     .Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("ProjectedKey", detachedQuery));
```

Comment: Thanks Radim, the solution works for the simple problem i have posted, but the real problem is more complex than i have wrote. I was trying to adapt this to my situation but i'm not getting there. imagine that in (CAST(colA_1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + CAST(colA_2 AS VARCHAR(10))) i don't want colA_2 but i want colC_2 from table C. This is because i have a composite key in EntityA as you defined in your solution

Comment: This is too complex. Such scenarios exceed ability of the ORM tools. It is not designed to solve NON standard keys. Even from DB perspective, such queries are the most uneffective. I wish to be able to give you genral solution with NHibernate here... but the only way is to fix the DB design. Seriously. You can do it now or later, but my experiences says: no other way... sorry. Good luck with NHibernate anyhow ;)

Comment: Thanks again Radim, i managed to use formula parameter to achive what i want, example here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114619/using-a-property-mapping-with-a-formula-in-nhibernate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114619/using-a-property-mapping-with-a-formula-in-nhibernate) but the drawback is the mixing of pure sql that will break the advantage of integrity between the c# model and DB.